# powerup and power down delay circuit

Tags: transistors, mosfet, delay, power-up-conditions

I have a customer requirement to enable and disable enable pin of regulator using GPIO. We a delay circuit in between. Delay is required both for powerup and power down condition. Can someone suggest me a circuit for powerup and power down delays using transistor or mosfet.

Comment: If you are using a GPIO, then you should put the delay in the software that drives the GPIO, rather than in the signal produced by the GPIO.

Comment: We need to provide an option for a hardware circuit to implement a delay.

Comment: How long a delay?  With what sort of precision?  The same in both directions?  What's your tolerance for power consumption by the circuit?

Comment: We need a delay of 100ms for powerup and 2seconds for power down. The power consumption by the circuit should be in mW.

Comment: Check out some audio power amps they have a delay for power on for the speaker output.